view field value does not change as expected ... stuck in cache?
My site is in Drupal 10
I have created a view by duplicating 'content' view in the core. I have reduced the duplicated view only to show

node title
node type
author
last update date-time of the node
number of comments
whether the node has new content

This last column comes from history module (I think) and it shows a "NEW" marker if the node content is new or a comment is added since you last saw the node.
This works properly when an authenticated user opens the view ... The user sees the "New" mark , when they should see it.........If then, the user opens the node and reads the contents, and again goes back to the view, One would expect that the "NEW" marker will go away.
However that does not happen. ..............Even when the view is observed again after a long time.
But if I go to admin/config/development/performance and clear the cache, .... and then the user visits the view, the NEW marker is not seen (and this is proper state of affairs)
What am I missing here? I need to do something so that when the user visits that "NEW" marked page, the corresponding information in the view should be refreshed when the next time view is opened.... How do I make it happen (other than of course ... .clear the cache from admin menu)

Sounds like the history module doesnt clear caches based on tags. You'll need to change the view "caching" setting to no caching or time based:



I tried this with "None" caching option; however did not notice any change in the behavior. For now, I have removed that column. Next round  I will try with Time based caching and see. Thanks for your prompt help.
